Did Nebuchadnezzar ascend to sovereignty on the day of the May 28, 602 BC [Gregorian proleptic corrected] eclipse?
I was reading the Babylonian chronicle and it stated that Nebuchadnezzar had an accession year and ascended to sovereignty on Ululu 1:

For twenty-one years Nabopolassar had been king of Babylon, when on 8 Abu he went to his destiny; in the month of Ululu Nebuchadnezzar returned to Babylon and on 1 Ululu he sat on the royal throne in Babylon. In the accession year Nebuchadnezzar went back again to the Hatti-land and until the month of Sabatu.

It also stated that the king of Judah was taken captive in the seventh year of Nebuchadnezzar on Adaru 2:

In the seventh year, the month of Kislîmu, the king of Akkad mustered his troops, marched to the Hatti-land, and besieged the city of Judah and on the second day of the month of Addaru he seized the city and captured the king.

According to the Bible the captivity of Jehoachin and his mother was in the eighth year of Nebuchadnezzar:

Jehoiachin king of Judah, his mother, his attendants, his nobles and his officials all surrendered to him.  In the eighth year of the reign of the king of Babylon, he took Jehoiachin prisoner. 2 Kings 24:12-13 New International Version

Now there was a solar eclipse maximum in Babylon on Julian day number 1501314.5 = May 18, 603 BC [Gregorian proleptic uncorrected] = May 28, 602 BC [Gregorian proleptic corrected] according to NASA, see the link below:
Babylonian eclipse
Ptolemy's Almagest should have that eclipse, but it doesn't. So my question is, "Did Nebuchadnezzar ascend to sovereignty on the day of the May 28, 602 BC [Gregorian proleptic corrected] eclipse?"
A solar eclipse can only happen on a new moon, which is on the first of the month. Ululu 1 meets that criterion. I was thinking that the Babylonians were using a solunar calendar, and the Jews a lunar calendar back then. So I want to use the fall of the house of Judah on Av 9, 586 BC to tie the ascension of Nebuchadnezzar to that eclipse. From Ululu 1, accession Nebuchadnezzar to Nisanu 1, 1 Nebuchadnezzar there were 30+29+30+29+30+29+30+29 days. Now go forward in time 19 lunar years to get to Av 9, 586 BC the known date of the fall of the house of Judah.
Accession Nebuchadnezzar was an intercalary year, so day 1 of the first year of Nebuchadnezzar was
1501314.5 + 4×30 + 4×29 = 1501550.5
Thus the first day of 7th Nebuchadnezzar was
1501550.5 + 354×3+376×3
So Adaru 2, 7th Nebuchadnezzar was  30×6+29×5+1 days later.
Now the goal is to see when this was in the Hebrew calendar.
1570416.5 = Nisan 1, 413 BC [Hebrew]
So my calculator tells me
Adaru 2, 7th Nebuchadnezzar [Babylonian] =
Av 8, 8th Nebuchadnezzar [Hebrew]
Thus it appears to me that Tisha B' Av = Av 9 th = Jewish day of most sadness commemorates the start of the Babylonian captivity not the day of the fall of Jerusalem.
Thus we must look for an alternate date for the fall of the house of Judah, and the Bible provides one.

In the twelfth year of our exile, in the tenth month on the fifth day, a man who had escaped from Jerusalem came to me and said, “The city has fallen!” Ezekiel 33:21 New International Version

If Ezekiel met this man, surely he inquired about the date of the fall of Jerusalem.  It doesn't seem important to put in the Torah the very day Ezekiel met this man.  On the basis of these two facts, the fall of the house of Judah was on Shebat 5.  Now we can use that date to determine the year of the fall of Judah.  Sources are conflicted as to whether the year was 586 or 587 BC.  According to the Bible, Jerusalem fell in 19th Nebuchadnezzar.
1501314.5 = Nisan 2, 602 BC Accession Neb.
1501608.5 = Nisan 1, 601 BC 1 Nebuchadnezzar
1501608.5+19×295.3-24 = 1507195.5 = July 3, 586 BC
Thus, if Nebuchadnezzar ascended to sovereignty on the day of the eclipse then Av 9 is the day of the start of the Babylonian captivity, and the fall of the house of Judah wasn't on Av 9, 586 BC it was on Shebat 5, 586 BC=July 3, 586 BC.
Edit - The July 3rd day is conspicuous looking, I think the Jews deliberately wanted it to work out to July 4th, because they calculated the flood of Noah occurred on July 4th, 1646 BC. To account for the one day discrepancy I had to rethink how the Jews handled leap days.  The idea I had was that they had 4 years of 295 days, and then a 296 day year. Then after 10 years they had two 296 day years in a row.  Based on this, we can determine the Julian day numbers of Av 9, 8th Neb. and Shebat 5, 19th Neb.
HEBREW
1501314.5 = Nisan 2, accession Nebuchadnezzar
1501314.5+294+295+295+295+296+295+295+295+30+29+30+8 = 1503771.5 = Av 9, 8th Nebuchadnezzar
BABYLONIAN
1501314.5 = Ululu 1, accession Nebuchadnezzar
1501550.5 Nisanu 1, 1 Nebuchadnezzar
1501550.5+354×3+376×3+30×6+29×5+1= 1504066.5 = Adaru 2, 7 Nebuchadnezzar
Since they don't agree one of them lies by a year.
1504066.5 - 1503771.5 = 295 days
Since this is 295 rather than 365, it was the Jews who lied by a year.  Thus, the start of the Babylonian captivity was in 9th Nebuchadnezzar not 8th Nebuchadnezzar, that is, Av 9, 9th Neb. [Hebrew]= Adaru 2, 7th Neb. [Babylonian] = 1504066.5.
Now I will check to see if Shebat 5, 19th Nebuchadnezzar was on July 4th Julian proleptic, under the assumption that 1704977.5 = January 1st, 44 BC [Julian].
1501313.5 + 295×4×3+7×296+295-24 = 1507196.5 = July 4th, 586 BC.
Now my assumption that January 1st, 44 BC = 1704977.5 is actually based on the eclipse visible from Rome on Aprilius 1st, 685 BC [Archaic Roman].  The astronomy software Home Planet has the eclipse on Julian day number 1470868.5.  The software uses a synodic month of 29.530574 days.  But if you analyze Dionysus Exiguus' Easter tables, you will find that leap day in 516 AD was canceled by I think Justinian.  The emperor Augustus canceled leap day in 16 BC.  These were the only leap day cancelations from January 1st, 44 BC to January 1st, 1600.  Therefore
January 1st, 44 BC = 1704978.5.
Therefore, Home Planet has the wrong day of the eclipse, it was on 1470869.5.  The software uses 29.530574 days per synodic month, but the actual value is according to my current estimate 29.530534 days per synodic month.
This means NASA has the wrong day of the Babylonian eclipse.
Home Planet has lunation 0 in December 1922, at
2423392.25 full moon
2423377.4847 new moon
Thus,  using 29.530534 days per synodic month the Babylonian eclipse occurred on
2423377.4847 - 31224×29.530534 = 1501316.091
This is one day after NASA's date for the Babylonian eclipse.
Using Nisan 1, accession Neb. = 1501315.5
and January 1, 44 BC = 1704978.5, calendrical analysis shows
Shebat 5, 19th Nebuchadnezzar was on July 4th Julian proleptic, since 1704978.5 = January 1st, 44 BC [Julian].
1501314.5 + 295×4×3+7×296+295-24 = 1507197.5 = July 4th, 586 BC [Julian proleptic]
FLOOD OF NOAH
2423392.25 - 44136×29.530534 = 1120032.601 = July 4th, 1646 BC [Julian proleptic]

You're using the date of the eclipse but what are you using to tie the ascension to the date of the eclipse?

@SteveBird Agreed. There's a lot of missing information here.

All of this "reasoning" is completely speculative. Lots of baseless assumptions here.

"Now there was a solar eclipse maximum in Babylon on Julian day number 1501314.5 = May 18, 602 BC according to NASA" You're off by one. NASA is using astronomical year numbers which has a year 0. AD/BC does not have a year 0. Astronomical year 0 is 1 BC, year 1 is 2 BC, and year -602 is 603 BC. But your Julian number is correct.

@Schwern, there was a year zero between 1 BC and 1 AD.  If you want a link that shows the proof of this I can provide one.

@leepappas There is no year zero the Gregorian calendar, which is the only one relevant here because we're converting from the Astronomical calendar to the Gregorian calendar, but let's see what you've got.

@Schwern, the proof there was a year zero is here: https://historum.com/t/rome-was-founded-on-aprilius-1-685-bc-on-the-day-of-a-solar-eclipse.197433/

@leepappas As they are defined today, the Gregorian and Julian calendars have no year zero. The Astronomical calendar does. When NASA says -602 today they mean 603 BC. You can't "prove" otherwise. You're arguing, perhaps, some historical quirk. "Ianuarius 1, 44 BC = day 1 of the Julian calendar" Leaving aside the mixing of a Roman date with a modern year, you're off by one again; the first day was in 45 BC. Of course, "45 BC" didn't exist then, it was AUC (ab urbe condita) 709. AUC 753 is 1 BC and AUC 754 is 1 AD.

@Schwern, The proof in the link starts from day 1 of the Octaeteris 1570570.5 and locates day 1 of the Julian calendar.  If you take into account Augustus' leap day cancelation in 16 BC, and the 516 AD leap day cancelation then day 1 Julian is 1704978.5.  The proof from there is iron clad.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Schwern, you didn't understand the proof in the link.   There were 45 years from January 1, 44 BC to January 1, 1AD..  Therefore there was a year zero.

@Schwern This user is a known crackpot peddler. You're arguing with delusion.

First Thoughts.
Book VI of Ptolemy's Almagest which deals with eclipses, written 100-170 AD, focuses on the geometry of planetary motion. Specifically addressing the phenomena of the Sun and the Moon's motion, but it primarily relies on geocentric models and circular orbits. While Ptolemy's work was an impressive attempt to model celestial motion for its time, it is not accurate relative to the actual elliptical orbits of planets described by Kepler's laws of planetary motion, which were established over 1,400 years later.  It would not be accurate enough to predict   an eclipse 800 years in the past in Babylon with any confidence.

Question:
"Did Nebuchadnezzar ascend to sovereignty on the day of the May 18, 602 BC eclipse?"

Nebuchadnezzar II did not ascend to the throne on the day of the May 18, 603 BCE eclipse. Historical records indicate that Nebuchadnezzar became king of Babylon in 605 BCE, following the death of his father, Nabopolassar. His accession occurred shortly after his major victory at the Battle of Carchemish that same year.
There is no evidence linking Nebuchadnezzar's rise to sovereignty with any specific eclipse, including the one on May 18, 603 BCE. Eclipses were significant astronomical events in ancient Mesopotamia and 3 were recorded by scribes, but there is no historical connection between this specific eclipse and Nebuchadnezzar's accession to the throne.

Note, the eclipse was in 603 BC. NASA is using the astronomical year -602 which is 603 BC.

@Schwern, the eclipse was on May 28, 602 BC [Gregorian proleptic corrected] = May 18, 603 BC [Gregorian proleptic uncorrected]
